# Grails - Self-referencing relationships

Tags: grails, grails-orm

When I write the following class, I get the following compilation error:

> could not resolve property

How can I achive the following:

```
class Employee{
  String Name
  String Email
  Employee Manager
  static hasMany = [desginations:Designation]    

  static constraints = {
  Name(unique:true)
  Email(unique:true)
  }
```

Thanks,
Much appreciated.

Comment: just to make it more clear I don't know how to assign an Employee a Manager who inturn is also an Employee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GORM can be picky about following its naming convention.  In particular, field names should be camelCase, starting with a lower case letter.

With the following definition:

```
class Employee {
    String name
    String email
    Employee manager

    static constraints = {
        name(unique:true)
        email(unique:true)
        manager(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

I can create an employee with a manager like so:

```
manager = new Employee(name: 'manager', email: 'manager@example.com')
manager.save()
employee = new Employee(name: 'employee', email: 'employee@example.com')
employee.manager = manager
employee.save()
```

Edit:
As fabien7474 noted, the important part is the manager(nullable:true) constraint.  This allows employee records to be saved without assigning a manager.  In the above example, the employee named `manager` is `employee`'s manager, but `manager` itself doesn't have a manager.  This is represented by a NULL value in the manager column in the database.

Comment: Thanks mate for your reply,
However, In case if I have to Edit a employee who I assigned as Manager, in that case, Grails doesnt let me assign a null value to the manager. which leads to a problem that a Manager has to be assigned a Manager.
I hope you understand what I mean

this only happens when I edit a Manager.

Comment: Should not occur if you assign the constraints manager(nullable: true)

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, 

I did have the manager(nullable:true) in my employee domain.
I do not see an empty option in the list box of manager when I edit a Manager. I am forced to assign a manager to the one I am editing.

Comment: The auto generated scaffold view will allow you to select blank for the manager field once the nullable constraint is added.  If you've customized the views add a noSelection="${['null':'']}" to the manager g:select tags in the view gsps.  If not, just run "grails generate-views Employee" to recreate the views from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate,
`noSelection` thats exactly what I was looking for.

Cheers.